# How do I have the console display only ONE output at a time?

Tags: java

So I'm making a clock program on Java, and in the console, it displays all the outputs, as it repeated goes in loops. Here's my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clock
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    throws InterruptedException
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("HOUR: ");

        int hrs = Input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("MIN: ");

        int min = Input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("SEC: ");

        int sec = Input.nextInt();

        while (true)
        {
        System.out.println(hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec);

        sec = sec + 1;

        if (sec > 59)
        {
            sec = 0;

            min = min + 1;
        }
        if (min > 59)
        {
            min = 0;

            hrs = hrs + 1;
        }
        if (hrs > 12)
        {
            hrs = 1;
        }
        Thread.sleep (1000);
        }
    }
}
```

In the console, I get:
    9:43:35
9:43:36
9:43:37
9:43:38
9:43:39
9:43:40

How can I have it such that it shows only the current time, and not the time displayed before?